Addressing High Volume Google Analytics Data Filtering in Power BI Using Python: Seeking Solutions
I'm encountering an issue in Power BI where I need to filter Google Analytics data by event name before making the request, as the volume of data is extremely high. Therefore, I've decided to use Python to perform this filter, but I'm struggling to implement it. I'm seeking suggestions to resolve this problem, even if it involves using other tools.
Above is the request I am currently using.
from google.analytics.data_v1beta import BetaAnalyticsDataClient
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import DateRange, Dimension, Metric, RunReportRequest, OrderBy, DimensionValue

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'client_secrets.json'

property_id = "******"

request = RunReportRequest(
    property='properties/'+property_id,
    dimensions=[Dimension(name="customEvent:uuid"), 
            Dimension(name="customEvent:page_url"),
            Dimension(name="eventName")],        
    metrics=[Metric(name="averageSessionDuration"), 
         Metric(name="activeUsers")],
    order_bys = [OrderBy(dimension = {'dimension_name': 'customEvent:uuid'}),
            OrderBy(dimension = {'dimension_name': 'customEvent:page_url'})],
    date_ranges=[DateRange(start_date="2024-01-5", end_date="today")],
    )

